# Comparing items in a python list list with only it's N neighbors both side of that item

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 500 Image files in Python and I'm trying to compare each image of the list with both the N neighbors to its left and the N neighbors to its right. I neighbors If there aren't N neighbors to the right I just want to compare it with future elements until I reach the end of the list, and vice versa if there aren't N neighbors to the left.

Comment: Sounds pretty simple.  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: what's the criteria of comparison? and where are you facing the problem during execution of your plan?

Comment: Actually I am trying to compare them using dhash library and images are large so it takes time Is there any better and fast way to do it. @Samwise

Comment: What are you trying to get out of the comparison?

Comment: I a sorting out unique images and there is a very high chance that for each image only it's 10 or 15 neighbor images are similar @Samwise

Comment: Maybe you should share the code you've written so far.  If you're calling `dhash` each time you make a comparison instead of keeping the dhashes in memory, there's an obvious opportunity for optimization there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll work. Note that you don't have to compare items to the left and right (i.e., you don't have to both compare item[n] with item[n+1], and compare item[n+1] with item[n]).

```
def compare_values(values, n, compare):

    for i in range(0, len(values)):

        # compare left
        x = i - n
        if x < 0:
            x = 0
        if x < i:
            for j in range(x, i):
                compare(values[i], values[j])

        # compare right
        x = i + n + 1
        if x > len(values):
            x = len(values)
        if x > i:
            for j in range(i + 1, x):
                compare(values[i], values[j])
```

Here's how you can validate this solution.

```
def print_values(item1, item2):
    print("Compare {} to {}".format(item1, item2))

def main():
    values = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eigth', 'ninth', 'tenth' ]
    n = 3
    compare_values(values, 3, print_values)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```